# Server runs Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and says that the new release 22.04.3 LTS is available?

Tags: ubuntu

When I login to this Ubuntu server I see the following welcome message. The server is running 20.04.6, but the new release 22.04.3 is still available.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-92-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/pro

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.

3 additional security updates can be applied with ESM Apps.
Learn more about enabling ESM Apps service at https://ubuntu.com/esm

New release '22.04.3 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2025.
```

lsb_release gives the following information:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS is indeed available and the previous LTS can easily upgrade to the current one. Why would this be a bug?

Comment: @John, 20.04 LTS EOL, with free *Pro* Expanded Security Maintenance, is through **2030**: https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle. Though one could change to 22.04, there are reasons some might not wish to do so, e.g., comfort with current setup, 22.04's increased reliance on SNAP, Wayland display as default, etc. **Thanks to Ubuntu** for giving us the choice!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I misread 20.04 and thought it was already on 22.04. Then 22.04.3 would be a downgrade from 22.04.6, but it was 20.04.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu puts out a Long Term Support versions (LTS) every 2 years in April.  Your server is just letting you know the current LTS version is available to upgrade to.  This is normal and expected behavior.

Ubuntu LTS releases receive 5 years of standard security maintenance for all packages in the 'Main' repository.  With an Ubuntu Pro subscription, you get access to Expanded Security Maintenance (ESM) covering security fixes for packages in both the 'Main' and 'Universe' repositories for 10 years.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I misread 20.04 and thought it was already on 22.04.